# Bind XML to autocomplete box windows phone

Tags: xml, windows-phone-7

Is it possbile to get a list of the items with a node in xml and then use those items in the auto complete text box in windows phone?

Answer (score 2):

The following may be a good starting point "Data Binding the Windows Phone Toolkit AutoCompleteBox" :-

http://www.windowsphonegeek.com/articles/Data-Binding-the-Windows-Phone-Toolkit-AutoCompleteBox

http://www.reddit.com/r/wp7dev/search?q=autocompletebox&restrict_sr=on&sort=relevance

Answer (score 0):

You can handle the Populating event to link the AutoCompleteBox to dynamically generated data.

[This](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.autocompletebox.populating(v=vs.95).aspx) is what you are looking for. It's a good article with a good example. And as mention don't forget to call PopulateComplete() when the manual population operation is complete.

You can also set the ItemFilter property to a custom Filter for defining your own search logic. See [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.autocompletebox.filtermode(v=vs.95).aspx) for details. Remember to set the FilterMode to Custom.

Comment: This question needs improvement. Bring in code snippets